# Load image from url to Recyclerview

Tags: android, image-loading

I have an app that loads content from a database as well as images from the internet. I am using a `RecyclerView` along with `CardView` to display my content in a list form.

Each row has an image on the left side and text on the right. 
The problem is that the text loads fast but the image takes time to load, so I want the image to continue loading in the background and then load into the `ImageView` object once loading is complete. I have no idea how to tackle this.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

Comment: what are you using for downloading image from database?? can you post the code?

Comment: i guess here you will find detailed answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/30769592/3498931 hope it helps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for this situation, but u can also use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and many more libraries. The documentation is pretty simple.

Answer (score 6):

Try Picasso:http://square.github.io/picasso/

It's a one liner in onBindViewholder():
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(viewHolder.imageView);